# mapping between arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mapping

I have some data in one array that I want to map into another array, given an array of correspondences:

- `originaldata` is a numpy 2D array,
- `targetdata` is another numpy 2D array,
- `mapping` is an array that maps between positions, so `mapping[x,y]` gives me a pair of coordinates of where the data of `targetdata[x,y]` comes from in `originaldata`.

So far I do something like this:

```
for (x,y) in ALLTHEPOINTS:
    targetdata[x,y]=originaldata[mapping[x,y][0],mapping[x,y][1]]
```

...which I suspect is very inefficient.

Is there any way to vectorize this? Or is there any numpy function that addresses this type of operation?

Comment: are you sure about your code? Should it be `targetdata[x,y]=originaldata[mapping[x, y, 0],mapping[x, y, 0]]`?

Comment: @BiRico Oh yeah sorry, I'll edit that. I was just writing that by heart...

Comment: So is `mapping` a 3d array, ie (X, Y, 2), or is it an array of tuples or something similar?

Comment: Numpy has a [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function, but it's not magic-speed-dust, just a wrapper for some `for`s.  Regardless, it's a good baseline; use it and worry only if profiling says to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what fancy indexing is there for:

```
targetdata = originaldata[mapping[..., 0], mapping[..., 1]]
```

As a simple example:

```
>>> original_data = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> original_data
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> mapping = np.array([[[1,0], [1, 1], [1, 2]],   # swap rows and reverse
...                     [[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 0]]]) # the second one
>>> original_data[mapping[..., 0], mapping[..., 1]]
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```